# Birthday Problem: Expected number of people in a room

Tags: probability, expected-value, binomial-distribution, birthday

If an infinite amount of people enter a room one by one, what is the expected number of people in the room when you first find two that share the same birthday?
(Assuming no leap years and every birthday is equally likely).

Comment: There isn't enough information.  There could be two, there could be a billion.  No way to tell.  Did you have some sort of prior assumption regarding the number of people in the room?

Comment: Yeah there's definitely not enough information here to say much

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose, I've tried to clarify the question. Is there enough information now?

Comment: Yes, the question is very different now.  Can you compute the probability that the first duplicate oocurs when person $n$ enters?

Comment: What have you tried, first of all?

Comment: @lulu I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. When person _n_ enters the room, the probability they share a birthday with someone else (since we have had no shared birthdays so far) is given by $ \frac{n-1}{365}$.

Comment: I am asking for the probability that the first duplicate occurs when the $n^{th}$ person enters.  Thus, you need the first $n-1$ birthdays to be distinct and then you need the $n^{th}$ to match one of those $n-1$.  Calling this $p_n$ we easily see that $p_2=\frac 1{365}$ for example.  As a check, once you have a formula for it, you should be able to confirm that $\sum_{n=1}^{365}p_n=1$.

Comment: @lulu I've come up with $p_n = \frac{n-1}{365}$ but $\sum_{n=1}^{365} p_n \neq 1$ for that formula.

Comment: Well, that means your formula for $p_n$ is wrong.  Just compute $p_3$ carefully to see that your formula isn't right even in that case.

Comment: @lulu I'm unable to come up with anything else. Shouldn't $p_3 = \frac{2}{365}$ since of the 365 birthdays the 3rd person could have, two would result in a duplicate?

Comment: In order for the third person to be the first duplicate, you need the first two people not to be duplicates.  Think about it, your formula says that the probability that the $365^{th}$ person is the first duplicate is nearly $1$.  But that would be an absurdly rare event.

Comment: Why not try an easier problem?  If you are tossing a fair coin, what's the expected number of tosses until you see a duplicate?  Same thing for a fair die.

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2361145/expanding-birthday-paradox-expected-value) is a duplicate of your question.  But you should try the simpler problems I proposed before looking up the answer.

Comment: @lulu sorry I misunderstood what you were asking. I thought we were basing $p_n$ off of the assumption that we had no duplicates so far. Once I find $p_n$, how would I approach calculating my expected value?

Comment: Also available [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Average_number_of_people)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever $N$ is a random variable which takes values in the non-negative integers $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$, there's a nice formula for the expected value $\mathbb{E}[N]$ of $N$:
$$\mathbb{E}[N] = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(N \geq n) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb{P}(N > n)$$

In this case, the second expression is the nicest, because if $N$ is the number of the first person who enters with a birthday matching a birthday in the room, then
$$\begin{align*}\mathbb{P}(N > n) &= \text{ Probability that none of the first } n \text{ people has a birthday in common with another} \\ &= \left(\frac{365}{365}\right)\left(\frac{364}{365}\right)\cdots\left(\frac{366-n}{365}\right) \\ &= \frac{365!}{365^n(365-n)!} \qquad \text{ if } 0\leq n \leq 365 \text{ and zero otherwise}\end{align*}$$

Then
$$\mathbb{E}[N] = \sum_{n=0}^{365} \frac{365!}{365^n(365-n)!} \approx 24.616586$$

Note that this is close to, but not equal, the [well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) median of $23$.  In fact, if you scroll down that page to [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Average_number_of_people), you'll see the same formula we derived along with the same result we've found for the expected value.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but as far as I see your probability is wrong since based on what I said (which is plain clear) you're actually saying that the number of n-tuples with elements from 1 to 365 is equal to $\frac{365^n}{n!}$ but this is clearly wrong since you're ignoring a lot of cases. (not every tuple is counted $n!$ times)

Comment: @AryanHemmati Use ordered selection.  There are $\binom{365}{n}n!$ permutations of length $n$ from $\{1,2,\ldots,365\}$ and $365^n$ $n$-tuples with entries from $\{1,2,\ldots,365\}$.  If you use some concept of an unordered $n$-tuple, as you are trying to do in your comment, then not all of these "unordered $n$-tuples" will be equally likely, so you cannot compute the probability as you have attempted to do.

Comment: Yes you're right

Comment: Thanks a lot‌...

Answer (score 0):

According to Pigeonhole Principle the number of people in the room shall at least be 366 to ensure what you're saying. However it "is" possible for less people in the room but this is the number you can be sure that at least two of the people share their birthday

Comment: Supposing infinitely many people enter a room one-by-one, shouldn't it be possible to calculate what, on average, the amount of people in the room would be when a shared birthday is found? The same way one could calculate the expected number of coin flips to get x consecutive heads?

Comment: What do you mean of "average"? Are you asking for a probability of existing two people in the room that have the same birthday for $n$ people inside the room?

Comment: @AryanHemmati. No, I know how to find the probability for _n_ people. I'm trying to find what the expected value of _n_ is once I find a shared birthday (assuming we are incrementing _n_ until a shared birthday is found).

Comment: ah, is that a valid way of finding expected values? Would it just be $\frac{n-1}{365} \geq \frac{1}{2}$ or $n=184$?

Comment: @Bruce Finding the median is a useful exercise, but no, it's not the same as the expected value, nor can you compute either like that...

Comment: There is no ambiguity at all in the phrase "expected value".