# Why is $(1 - \frac{1}{p})^n$ close to $e^{-\frac{n}{p}}$ when $n$ and $p$ are large?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Looking at this answer by Henry [birthday problem - expected number of collisions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35791/birthday-problem-expected-number-of-collisions) and struggling to figure out why it matches this other formula provided to me on a programming related question. Thanks!

Comment: $(1 - 1/p)^n = [(1 - 1/p)^{p}]^{n/p}$, and $(1 - 1/p)^p$ approaches $e^{-1}$ for large $p$.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong You should make that an answer!

Comment: you may get confused if you have seen other definitions of $e$, as maybe convergence series. There many ways to get $e$ one of  the most common is the one mentioned by Christopher.

Answer (score 3):

What you may not know is that $e$ can be *defined* as
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} (1+1/x)^x$$
from which it follows (by a little bit of limit manipulation) that $$\lim_{x \to \infty} (1+r/x)^x=e^r$$
The formula you are asking about can be explained from this; see Christopher Wong's comment above.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are familiar with Taylor series, but if yes :
$$\left(1-\frac1p\right)^n=\exp\left(n\ln\left(1-\frac1p\right)\right)=\exp\left(-n\left(\frac1p+o\left(\frac1p\right)\right)\right)$$
and this gives :
$$\left(1-\frac1p\right)^n\sim_{p>>1} \exp\left(-\frac{n}{p}\right)$$

Note than there's no assumption on n.