# Birthday Problem: Expected Number of people with common birthday

Tags: probability, solution-verification, expected-value, birthday

This might be a different variant of the typical birthday problem. Given a room of $n$ people, let $N$ be a random variable representing the number of people who have a birthday common with at least one other person. I will start by writing $$N = P_1 + P_2 + \cdots + P_n$$
where $P_i$ is an indicator random variable which is $1$ when person i's birthday is common with at least one other person in the room.

So we have by symmetry

\begin{align*}
 E[N] &= n E[P_1] 
\end{align*}

Now I note that person $1$'s birthday $D_1$ is a uniform random variable taking values in $\{1,2, ..., 365 \}$. Same for other people. Hence, by total expectation theorem

\begin{align*}
 E[N] &= n E[P_1]\\
&= n \sum_{k = 1}^{365} P(D_1 = k) E[P_1 | D_1 = k]\\
&= n \sum_{k = 1}^{365} \frac{1}{365} E[P_1 | D_1 = k]\\
&= n \sum_{k = 1}^{365} \frac{1}{365} \left(1 - \left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^{n-1} \right)\\
&= n\left(1 - \left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^{n-1} \right)
\end{align*}

Is this right? If not, help me correct my argument. Thanks.

Comment: It is not clear if you are asking a question. If you are, then what is your question? If you are not, then what is it that you would like us to do with your post?

Comment: Yes just proof verification or correction. Thanks.

Comment: Your calculation of $E[P_1]$ is not correct.  There is no reason for persons 2 and 3 NOT to share a birthday if we are only concerned with the event $\{P_1=0\}$.

Comment: yes I see. How about now?

Comment: Yes, you have fixed the mistake.  Now it is correct.

Comment: related https://math.stackexchange.com/a/35798/6460